# Getting MethodNotAllowed in Bot Framework

Tags: frameworks, bots, azureportal

I have registered basic echo microsoft bot template into Azure portal but I am getting following error in the response:

```
Operation returned an invalid status code ‘MethodNotAllowed"
```

Note: Same piece of code is working fine in local and old registered bots into azure portal. But facing above issue with newly registered Bot and i have verified messaging endpoints, app id and credentials etc.

Has anyone run into the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

The Bot Framework State service will be deprecated on March 31st, 2018. This means that by default, bots registered with the Bot Framework will no longer be able to rely on the state service to send and retrieve conversation contextual conversation state information to and from their bots.

more details:
https://blog.botframework.com/2017/12/19/bot-state-service-will-soon-retired-march-31st-2018/